# capture last line of file as integer variable and use in awk command

Tags: awk

I am trying to capture the last line of a file as a variable for use in an awk command.

Here is an example of the file (the end of it) :

```
cat file.txt 
....
 phylum:Chlorophyta 1
 phylum:Mucoromycota 1
column 6:
 superkingdom:Eukaryota 99
column 7:
 
 99
```

I want to use that '99' as an integer in an awk command, saving it as a variable,

```
tail -n1 file.txt
99
```

e.g.

```
div=$(tail -n1 file.txt)

echo $div
99
```

To be used in a 2nd file (conf.txt), to divide the numbers in the 2nd field:

```
cat conf.txt
Class 88
Family 78
Genus 44
Species 23
```

BUT, when I try to use the `$div` variable in the awk command (using `-v` flag as suggested here and elsewhere with awk when taking a variable) I get this error:

```
awk -v a=$div '{print $2/a}' conf.txt 
awk: can't open file {print $2/a}
 source line number 1
```

But when saivng 99 as a variable simply on the cmd line,  It works just fine:

```
num=99
awk -v a=$num '{print $2/a}' conf.txt 
0.888889
0.787879
0.444444
0.232323
```

Are there extra spaces/characters in the capture from `tail -1`? I am missing something simple, but fundamental.

Ultimatey, I don't even want to have to save as a separate variable first If I dont have to, instead, just capture that last line number (99) and put directly into an awk cmd, e.g.:

```
awk  '{print $2/[tail -1 file.txt]}' conf.txt
```

This is psuedo code (in the brackets)  ...but, this would ultimately be what Id want...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use quotes. `awk -v a="$div" '{print $2/a}' conf.txt`

Comment: You seem to be asking for help implementing the wrong approach to doing something. Instead of asking how to read a value from the last line of a file and then pass that value to awk, you should almost certainly simply be doing something like calling awk to read that file and use the last line of it when processing the next file. This feels a lot like an [XY Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a space at the beginning of the last line, so the command is becoming

```
awk -v a= 99 '{print $2/a}' conf.txt
```

This is setting `a` to an empty string, treating `99` as the awk script, and the rest as filenames.

Remove the spaces from `$div`.

```
div=${div// /}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes as a habit in the shell.

Given:

```
cat file
blah blah
   99
```

The command `n=$(tail -n1 file)` produces leading spaces in front of the 99:

```
n=$(tail -n1 file)
printf "\"%s\"\n" "$n"
"   99"
```

It is especially a bug that bites when you *think* you are checking the value of `$n` without quotes because the leading spaces are stripped by the shell prior to invoking `echo`.

Consider:

```
echo $n         # no quotes - leading spaces stripped
99
echo "$n"       # preserve whitespace...
   99
```

Now if you try and pass that argument without quotes to awk, the space has meaning to the shell and screws up how the command is interpreted:

```
awk -v n=$n 'BEGIN{printf "\"%s\", %s\n", n, n+1}'
awk: fatal: cannot open file `BEGIN{printf "\"%s\", %s\n", n, n+1}' for reading: No such file or directory
```

vs:

```
awk -v n="$n" 'BEGIN{printf "\"%s\", %s\n", n, n+1}'
"   99", 100
```

If you want to use `awk` to replace the use of `tail` you use the idiom of `FNR==NR` to test if the file is the first file and `$1==$1+0` to test if `awk` is interpreting what it sees as a number:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {n=$1+0==$1 ? $1+0 : n; next} # n ends up being the last number seen
$2==$2+0{print $2/n}
' file conf.txt
0.888889
0.787879
0.444444
0.232323
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than have shell call some command to get the last line of file.txt then save it in a shell variable, then set an awk variable to that same value populated from  the shell variable and passing it to awk, just use one call to awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{n=$1; next} {print $2/n}' file.txt conf.txt
0.888889
0.787879
0.444444
0.232323
```

Answer (score 0):

Enabling debug mode and running the `awk` command:

```
$ set -x
$ awk -v a=$div '{print $2/a}' conf.txt
+ awk -v a= 99 '{print $2/a}'
awk: fatal: cannot open file `{print $2/a}' for reading: No such file or directory
```

Of interest:

- `-v a=`  - define `awk` variable `a` as being empty
- `99` - `awk` code/script
- `'{print $2/a}'` - first file passed to `awk` script, and the source of the error message

As others have pointed out you can get around the error by wrapping `$div` in double quotes:

```
$ awk -v a="$div" '{print $2/a}' conf.txt
+ awk -v 'a=  99' '{print $2/a}' conf.txt
0.888889
0.787879
0.444444
0.232323
```

Of interest:

- `-v '=  99'` - define `awk` variable `a` and string `'  99'`
- in this case `awk` ignores the spaces when the rest of the variable can be interpreted as a numeric
- `'{print $2/a}'` - `awk` code/script
- `conf.txt` - file passed to `awk` script

Barmar and dawg have addressed stripping the blanks from `div` and using `awk` for the entire process, respectively.